# `CreateFile` for UWP in visual studio not available in <Windows.h>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Still familiarizing myself with VS, I wanted to use the method `CreateFile` in one of my source files for the UWP app I am building but the compiler says `'CreateFile': identifier not found...` I already included the header `<Windows.h>`. I tried it in a console application template and it works. Any suggestions?

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "pch.h"

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

class Serial
{
public:

    Serial(tstring &commPortName, int bitRate = 115200);
    ~Serial();
private:
    HANDLE commHandle;
    int write(const char *buffer);
};
```

Source:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Serial.h"

Serial::Serial(tstring &commPortName, int bitRate)
{
    commHandle = CreateFile(commPortName.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ |
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0, NULL);
}

Serial::~Serial()
{
    CloseHandle(commHandle);
}

int Serial::write(const char *buffer)
{
    DWORD numWritten;
    WriteFile(commHandle, buffer, strlen(buffer), &numWritten, NULL);

    return numWritten;
}
```

Comment: CreateFile is not available to  UWP applications.  This might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Btw.: PCH.h should always be the first include in a file.

Comment: similar issue when including Zlib project which open source library. error C3861: 'CreateFileA': identifier not found